# Python Tkinter ttk entry revert "show=" to default

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a program with Python and using Tkinter to create the GUI, and there is a password entry box that user can decide to show characters or hide them with a "*" character by a checkbutton.

I can configure the entry to hide the characters with a "*" character by following code:

```
Entry.configure(show="*")
```

But what should I do when I want to show the characters back? I looked to documentations but nothing was written about this issue. Should I completely remove the entry and recreate it without `show="*"`? Isn't there a short way to remove it?

I'm using Python 3.7.9.

Comment: Did you try an empty string?

Comment: @Atlas435 I can't believe why I didn't tried it! Thank you, setting it to a empty string made characters to show again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem got solved by setting the `show` parameter to a empty string like in the below code:

```
Entry.configure(show="")
```

Thanks for @Atlas435 from comments.